# Is there a tax treaty between US and Egypt?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, treaty, egypt

I'm a non-US citizen and I was asked to fill a Form W-8BEN. I googled and I know that there is a tax treaty between US and Egypt but I still don't know the percentage (default tax is 30%). It is also required to specify the type of income and why I should benefit from the treaty. I've never filled a  form like that before. So, I would like to know the types of income and reasons to apply tax reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.r.t. form W-8BEN, the instructions / explanation for the form are [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf). As far as the tax treaty is concerned, the document is [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/egypt.pdf), and the technical explanation is [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/egypttech.pdf). You will have to figure out under what treaty provision you can claim a benefit to put on line 10, or hire a specialist in the Egyptian-American tax situation for figure out how this applies to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Based on the documents you provided me, I submitted a request and they approved to reduce taxes. You're the best!